# Is there an npm command to list the number of dependencies each of my direct depedencies is pulling in?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I know that I can get a list of my direct dependencies via

`npm ls --depth=0 --only=production`

which produces something like this

```
my-app@1.1.0 /code/my-app
├── autosize@4.0.1
├── bluebird@3.5.1
├── blueimp-md5@2.10.0
├── buefy@0.6.5
├── bulma@0.6.2
├── bulma-badge@1.0.1
├── bulma-switch@0.1.12
├── d3-scale-chromatic@1.2.0
├── date-fns@1.29.0

... etc ...
```

Is there an easy way to get the output to look something like this?

```
my-app@1.1.0 /code/my-app
├── autosize@4.0.1 (4 dependencies)
├── bluebird@3.5.1 (28 dependencies)
├── blueimp-md5@2.10.0 (12 dependencies)
├── buefy@0.6.5 (30 dependencies)
├── bulma@0.6.2 (21 dependencies)
├── bulma-badge@1.0.1 (3 dependencies)
├── bulma-switch@0.1.12 (93 dependencies)
├── d3-scale-chromatic@1.2.0 (1 dependency)
├── date-fns@1.29.0 (7 dependencies)
```

Comment: Would this count be a recursive, deduped count of dependencies or just direct dependencies to the folder?

Comment: Ideally a recursive count. Basically trying to wrap up the things that would normally be displayed without the `--depth=0` into a count to see which packages are the heaviest

Answer (score 4):

I don’t think npm provides this natively. Shell script can do something similar:

```sh
for path in `npm ls --depth=0 --parseable`
do
    package=`basename path`
    echo "$package: `npm ls --parseable $package | wc -l` dependencies"
done
```

Hope this is “easy” enough? Note that some package could be counted multiple time, since transitive dependencies can overlap with each other. It’s also assumed that package names don’t contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

For those that find this question years later, take a look at [howfat](https://github.com/megahertz/howfat):

```bash
npx howfat
```

You can also list heaviest dependencies first (in terms of number of transitive dependencies):

```bash
npx howfat --sort dependencies-
```